# (React, Redux) Error occurs when I put my dispatch code in my onChange function

Tags: reactjs, redux

Error message occurs when I put a function that includes dispatch in my Component.

I checked the link that err msg gave me. 
I had right version of react to use, and not sure about other conditions.
(Breaking the Rules of Hooks
You can only call Hooks while React is rendering a function component:

✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a function component.
✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a custom Hook.)

And the Component works fine without dispatch code.

Here's parent component(this works fine)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Jumbotron } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Seoul, Gyeongi, Incheon, Busan, Daegue, Daejeon, Sejong, Gwangju, Ulsan, Gangwon, Gyungnam, Gyungbuk, Jeonnam, Jeonbuk, Choongnam, Choongbuk, Jeju, Othercountry } from './Locals/localbox';
import './Detailsrch.css';

class Detailsrch extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        var localselect = (e) => {
            console.log(e.target.getAttribute('name'));
            let selector = document.getElementsByClassName('locals');
            let selector_local = document.getElementsByClassName('localdiv');
            let i = 0;
            for (let j=0; j<selector_local.length; j++) {
                selector_local[j].style.display = 'none';
              }
            let boxclass = e.target.getAttribute('name');
            document.getElementsByClassName(boxclass)[0].style.display = 'block';
            while (selector[i]) {
                selector[i].className = 'locals';
                i++;
            }
            if(e.target.className=='localtext'){
                e.target.parentElement.className = 'locals localclick';
            } else {
                e.target.className = 'locals localclick';
            }
        }
        return (
            <Jumbotron className='searchjumbo'>
                <p>지역</p>
                <ul>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect}><span className='localtext'>전체</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv1'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv1'>서울</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv2'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv2'>경기</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv3'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv3'>인천</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv4'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv4'>부산</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv5'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv5'>대구</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv6'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv6'>대전</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv7'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv7'>세종</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv8'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv8'>광주</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv9'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv9'>울산</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv10'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv10'>강원</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv11'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv11'>경남</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv12'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv12'>경북</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv13'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv13'>전남</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv14'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv14'>전북</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv15'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv15'>충남</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv16'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv16'>충북</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv17'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv17'>제주</span></li>
                    <li className='locals' onClick={localselect} name='localdiv18'><span className='localtext' name='localdiv18'>해외</span></li>
                </ul>
                <Seoul/>
                <Gyeongi/>
                <Incheon/>
                <Busan/>
                <Daegue/>
                <Daejeon/>
                <Sejong/>
                <Gwangju/>
                <Ulsan/>
                <Gangwon/>
                <Gyungnam/>
                <Gyungbuk/>
                <Jeonnam/>
                <Jeonbuk/>
                <Choongnam/>
                <Choongbuk/>
                <Jeju/>
                <Othercountry/>
                <hr className='firsthr' />
                <p>형태</p><hr />

                <p>경력</p><hr />

                <p>국적</p><hr />

                <p>성별</p>
            </Jumbotron>
        );
    }
};
```

And here's the code where the problem is.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ToggleButton, ToggleButtonGroup } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { checked, notchecked } from '../../../actions';
import './localbox.css';
const dispatch = useDispatch();


export class Seoul extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        /* var btnclicked = (e) => {
            let btnname = e.target.getAttribute('name');
            if (e.target.children[0].checked = true) {
                return () => dispatch(checked(btnname));
            } else if (e.target.children[0].checked = false) {
                return () => dispatch(notchecked(btnname));
            };
        }; Here is my functino for onChange */
        // when I get rid of above code, this works fine.
        return (
            <div className='localdiv localdiv1'>
                <ToggleButtonGroup className='togglebtngrp' type="checkbox">
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn0' variant="outline-secondary" value={0} >전체</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' onChange={btnclicked} name="강남구" variant="outline-primary" value={1}>강남구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={2}>강동구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={3}>강북구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={4}>강서구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={5}>관악구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={6}>광진구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={7}>구로구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={8}>금천구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={9}>노원구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={10}>도봉구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={11}>동대문구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={12}>동작구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={13}>마포구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={14}>서대문구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={15}>서초구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={16}>성동구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={17}>성북구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={18}>송파구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={19}>양천구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={20}>영등포구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={21}>용산구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={22}>은평구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={23}>종로구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={24}>중구</ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn' variant="outline-primary" value={25}>중랑구</ToggleButton>
                </ToggleButtonGroup>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

I expect if I click the ToggleButton, onChange event will active and function btncliked will be executed.

But it keeps telling me
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
..
.
.
.
..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a Hook outside of a [React function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions).

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

You should use a function component in order to use hooks and place the `useDispatch` inside the function:

```js
const Seoul = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  var btnclicked = (e) => {
    let btnname = e.target.getAttribute('name');

    if (e.target.children[0].checked = true) {
      return () => dispatch(checked(btnname));
    } else if (e.target.children[0].checked = false) {
      return () => dispatch(notchecked(btnname));
    };
  };  


  return (
    <div className='localdiv localdiv1'>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Sadly, that code was there at first as you wrote. My bad that I didn't write it. But there was same err msg at that time too. I moved it again to make sure, and it still doesn't work. I'll update err msg in my question.

Comment: Well, it turns out it works fine if I don't use `class Seoul extends Component` and replace it as a const as you wrote. Can you tell me the difference between them and why Component didn't work? I still don't get it :(

Comment: Hooks can only be used in Function components (no classes). That is one of the Rules of Hooks. :-) Take a look at the link I've provided, it's pretty good explained there.